# Why are characters and forward slashes being appended to my NSURL?

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsurl

My images are not loading from their URLs. When I log the NSURL, it appears correct

> my.website.com/images/image1.png

But when I set breakpoints, the NSURL shows up in the debugger console as

> my.website.com/images/image1.png\x05\b

I have checked the json through my web browser, and it is perfectly valid. The string ends with the 'g' of "png".

I am using SDWebImage to asynchronously load images for my table cells. The URLs to be used for the pictures are coming from a php file that encodes the JSON.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SpotsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SpotCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

    if (self.spotDictionary)
    {
        NSDictionary* spot = (NSDictionary*)[self.spotDictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row]];
        NSString* title = [spot objectForKey:@"Title"];
        NSURL* imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:(NSString*)[spot objectForKey:@"Image"]]; NSLog(@"%@", imageURL);
        UIImage* placeholder = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];

        // See ~*~ below
        NSURL* testURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.hdwallpaperspot.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Volvo-station-wagon-612pb.jpg"];

        cell.nameLabel.text = title;

        [cell.pictureView setImageWithURL:imageURL
                         placeholderImage:placeholder]; // SDWebImage category for UIImage

//breakpoint here
    }

    return cell;
}
```

~*~
To make sure SDWebImage was performing correctly, I grabbed an image off the net to temporarily test the library, and it performed wonderfully. I have checked the class of the `"Image"` object and it is `_NSCFString`. The `(NSString*)` cast was added in case my understanding of the interchangeability between NSCFString and NSString is flawed. No luck.

Comment: This is a debugger issue. Search and you will find others reporting this issue. Type `po imageURL` in the debugger command line and you will see the expected value.

Comment: Yep, you're correct. But! The images will still not load from the `imageURL`. Yet they will from the `testURL`. And the URL is totally valid, I can copy it out of the log console and paste it in Firefox and it loads. So I can't help but think the strange characters are still doing voodoo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very embarrassing, but I'll share my mistake so no one gets misconcepted.

I forgot to specify the protocol (http://) in my `Image` JSON object. 
I figured NSURL class would have some sort of default HTTP checking, but I realize that's not feasible, as there are other protocols that could be used with an NSURL.

Thanks @rmaddy for pointing out the debugger, uhm, bug.